Fixed Button doubles, when moved on hover
I am making a website using Vue js and want to add a button for bot assistant in the bottom right. But as long as it's a button I want it to react somehow, so in hover, I wrote this:
.bot:hover {
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(2) translatey(-4.5vh);
}

And it would have worked perfectly if only it didn't double itself every time Mouse is on this button. There's some more code and screen of the problem:
.bot {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2vw;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.bot:hover {
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(2) translatey(-4.5vh);
}

.bot:not(:hover){
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.v-img{
  width: 20vh;
}

<button>
  <div class="bot">
    <v-img
      src="../assets/bot.png"
    />
  </div>
  </button>

As you can see Behind the big robot there is a small one

I tried to remove div, move the class bot from div to button, and change position from fixed to all other, making it invisible. In some cases nothing changed, in some, it wasn't fixed in the bottom left corner.
Here's full code of this bot component:
<template>
  <button class="bot">
    <v-img
      src="../assets/bot.png"
    />
  </button>
</template>

<style scoped>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bot {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2vw;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.bot:hover {
  transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.5) translatey(-2.5vh);
  background: none;
}

.bot:not(:hover){
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.v-img{
  width: 20vh;
}
</style>


Can you provide a reproducible example, it would be much easier to help you that way.? See - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
